# Associating pts and tty to a process

Tags: shell, tty, pts

I am trying to find out which tty or pts is being run by which process.

My research so far is that:

- tty is a kernel or backend terminal to handle lower level stuffs
- pts is a pesudo terminal to allow user to communicate with the system
- there are a lot of tty and pts files in `/dev` but cannot be read

Would like to ask the following questions:

- Why does `/dev/pts` and `/dev` contains so much numbers (eg 1-26) despite `ps -aux | grep  pts` only showing 4 pts entries
- Is it possible to determine what process is running a pts or tty? As I read that ssh spawns a new shell, but not sure if its a pts or tty